# How to get object from class to Service

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, aws-sdk

Here I have AmazonService class which contains ec2 object,

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2;
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2ClientBuilder;

@Component
public class AmazonService {

    private AmazonEC2 ec2 = AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1).build();

    public AmazonEC2 getEc2() {
        return ec2;
    }   
}
```

I need to get this ec2 from a service class as follows,

```
@Service
public class SecurityGroupServiceImpl implements SecurityGroupService {



    @Autowired
    AmazonService amazonService;

    final AmazonEC2 ec2 = amazonService.getEc2();

    @Override
    public DeleteSecurityGroupResult deleteSecurityGroup(SecurityGroupDTO securityGroupDTO) {

        DeleteSecurityGroupRequest request = new DeleteSecurityGroupRequest()
                .withGroupId(securityGroupDTO.getGroupID());

        DeleteSecurityGroupResult response = ec2.deleteSecurityGroup(request);
        System.out.println(response);
        return response;
    }
}
```

My Controller class is as follows,

```
@Controller
public class SecurityGroupController {

    @Autowired
    SecurityGroupService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteSecurityGroup", produces = "application/json", 
            consumes = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    private @ResponseBody DeleteSecurityGroupResult deleteSecurityGroup(@RequestBody SecurityGroupDTO securityGroupDTO){

        return service.deleteSecurityGroup(securityGroupDTO);
    }

}
```

When I tried to run this I am getting error as,

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-06-28 18:46:21.213 ERROR 7792 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityGroupController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityGroupServiceImpl' defined in file [E:\Project\AWS-SDK-Implimentation\target\classes\com\altimetrik\services\impl\SecurityGroupServiceImpl.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.altimetrik.services.impl.SecurityGroupServiceImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at com.altimetrik.AwsSdkImplimentationApplication.main(AwsSdkImplimentationApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityGroupServiceImpl' defined in file [E:\Project\AWS-SDK-Implimentation\target\classes\com\altimetrik\services\impl\SecurityGroupServiceImpl.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.altimetrik.services.impl.SecurityGroupServiceImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1155) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.altimetrik.services.impl.SecurityGroupServiceImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1147) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.altimetrik.services.impl.SecurityGroupServiceImpl.<init>(SecurityGroupServiceImpl.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

Here I am using ec2 object in various service class, so I don't want to initialize this every time in all the service class. Instead I need to create ec2 in separate class and consume it in all other service classes. But I am getting the above mentioned error on trying this. Someone help me out in fixing this issue.

Comment: What is line 35 of SecurityGroupServiceImpl.java? There you have a NullPointerException causing the complete Spring intialization to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even better, why not take advantage of Java config (perfect for instantiating beans from third parties) and just have the `AmazonEC2` as an actual Spring bean.

```
@Configuration
public class AmazonServiceConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public AmazonEC2 ec2() {
    return AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.standard()
      .withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1).build();
  }   
}
```

And your service implementation:

```
@Service
public class SecurityGroupServiceImpl implements SecurityGroupService {    
    @Autowired    
    AmazonEC2 ec2;

    @Override
    public DeleteSecurityGroupResult deleteSecurityGroup(SecurityGroupDTO securityGroupDTO) {

        DeleteSecurityGroupRequest request = new DeleteSecurityGroupRequest()
                .withGroupId(securityGroupDTO.getGroupID());

        DeleteSecurityGroupResult response = ec2.deleteSecurityGroup(request);
        System.out.println(response);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here when you try to set `ec2` from `SecurityGroupServiceImpl` class, which is not actually created at the time by `AmazonService` class. So try to get ec2 in `SecurityGroupServiceImpl` after loading `AmazonService` class

Answer (score 0):

When SecurityGroupServiceImpl is created there is no `amazonService`. It's autowired later so the attempt to get something produces NPE.

Instead move the init in `@PostConstruct`

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() throws Exception {
    ec2 = amazonService.getEc2();
}
```

Of course the field should not be final.

Alternatively remove the `@Autowire` from field and move to constructor and initialize the final field from the constructor (Read @Autowired on Constructors section here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_autowired_annotation.htm )